# WP - How to call posts by page parent category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a blog listings template for a site with multiple parent pages, and I need this page template to be used across the site, various pages will require there own blog listings page. Calling relevant posts depending on the Parent category.

i.e:

Food (Site Homepage)

- Food Blog (Listings page for all Food related posts)

Fruit (Parent page)

- Fruit Blog (Listings page for all Fruit related posts)

Veg (Parent page)

- Veg Blog (Listings page for all Veg related posts)

My problem is that the posts per correct parent category aren't being called. I'm getting all posts.

I've set my code up like this: Many thanks in advance.

```
<div id="bloglistings">

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

            <?php


            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $current_cat = intval( get_query_var('cat') );

            $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'posts_per_page'    => 6,
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'orderby'           => 'ID',
            );

            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="row">

            <?php $count=0; ?>    
            <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="span6">
            <div class="media feature one">
            <a class="pull-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-circle')); ?>
            <img class="hoverimage" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon-read-bloglistings.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
            <p><?php
            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            if ( $my_excerpt != '' ) {
            // Some string manipulation performed
            }
            echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page
            ?>
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <?php $count++; ?>

            <?php if ($count==2 ||$wp_query->found_posts==0) : 

            echo '</div><div class="row">';

            ?>

            <?php $count=0; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>                
            <h2>Sorry but there are no posts.</h3>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- PAGINATION -->

            <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
            <li>
            <?php
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

            echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big
            ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            ) );
            ?>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


            </div><!-- /.row -->

            </div><!--/bloglistings-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the category to the query.

Replace this:

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'orderby'           => 'ID',
        );
```

with

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'category__in'      => array( $current_cat ),// category was missing here
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'orderby'           => 'ID',
        );
```

Comment: Hi ALex, I had that in prior to posting it sorry. When I include the 'category__in' it breaks the template.